# Find source URLs for MapProxy

Tags: mapproxy

I am trying to get familiar with MapProxy. I was able to install and start the demo page as well as the OpenStreetMap configuration from here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapProxy

I am curious now about other sources, such as Bing Maps. Unfortunately I am not able to find the source URL of this service (like http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/%(tms_path)s.%(format)s for OpenStreetMap).

I can figure out the domain name by evaluating the get calls in the browser when using Bing Maps. But all the parameters after the domain name are a riddle to me.

Is there a page that shows such sources of different web map services or are they maybe not even communicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about MapProxy, but for **Bing** you can obtain tiles using the quadkey:

`http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/ho`**{quadkey}**`?g=671&mkt=en-US`

For a quadkey of *12021*:

```
http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/ho12021?g=671&mkt=en-US
```

A bit of explanation on the quadkey:

> To optimize the indexing and storage of tiles, the two-dimensional
>   tile XY coordinates are combined into one-dimensional strings called
>   quadtree keys, or “quadkeys” for short. Each quadkey uniquely
>   identifies a single tile at a particular level of detail, and it can
>   be used as an key in common database B-tree indexes.

Full explanation [available at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx).

**Google Maps** uses x,y and z for zoom:

```
http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@110&hl=pl&x=4594&y=2697&z=13
```

You just have to know [which combinations are valid](http://www.heywhatsthat.com/gmt.html).